# C# Excel add-in loops never terminate

Tags: c#, excel, backgroundworker, sqlconnection, excel-addins

I have written an add-in that reads values from a spreadsheet and populates a database. When I execute the add-in in debug mode from Visual studio it works correctly the first time. Without stopping the debugger when I try to upload values from another spreadsheet using the add-in the loops in my add-in never seem to end. I control them using the used range of the active sheet and for some reason after the loop counter hits the range count it gets reinitialized to the starting value and hence my database spits out an SqlException due to a violation of the unique key constraint.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = DataConnection.GetConnection())
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn))
            {
                SqlParameter termIDParam = myCommand.Parameters.Add("@tid", SqlDbType.Int);
                SqlParameter priceParam = myCommand.Parameters.Add("@price", SqlDbType.Decimal);
                SqlParameter ContractDateParam = myCommand.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime);
                SqlParameter pipelineIDParam = myCommand.Parameters.Add("@pid", SqlDbType.Int);
                string pipeline = activeSheet.Cells[1, 1].Value2.ToString();
                bool isNonDuplicate = true;
                int startRow = (pipeline.ToLower().Equals("henry hub")) ? 3 : 4;
                int startColumn = checkBox1.Checked ? 2 : 1;
                for (int i = startRow; i <= range.Rows.Count & isNonDuplicate; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = startColumn; j <= range.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        if (range.Cells[i, j].Value2 != null && !range.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString().Equals(" "))
                        {
                            string dateval = range.Cells[(startRow - 2), j].Value2.ToString();
                            double val = double.Parse(dateval);
                            DateTime contractDate = DateTime.FromOADate(val);
                            DateTime tempTerm = DateTime.FromOADate(activeSheet.Cells[i, 1].Value2);
                            string monthName = new DateTimeFormatInfo().GetAbbreviatedMonthName(tempTerm.Month);
                            string year = tempTerm.Year.ToString().Substring(2, 2);
                            string term = monthName + "-" + year;

                            double price = double.Parse(range.Cells[i,j].Value2.ToString());
                            SqlCommand subCommand = new SqlCommand();
                            subCommand.CommandText = "Select PipelineID from Pipeline where PipelineDescription='" + pipeline + "'";
                            subCommand.Connection = conn;
                            int pipeID = (int)subCommand.ExecuteScalar();
                            subCommand.CommandText = "Select TermID from Term where TermDescription = '" + term + "'";
                            int termID = (int)subCommand.ExecuteScalar();
                            termIDParam.Value = termID;
                            priceParam.Value = price;
                            ContractDateParam.Value = contractDate;
                            pipelineIDParam.Value = pipeID;
                            myCommand.Parameters["@tid"] = termIDParam;
                            myCommand.Parameters["@price"] = priceParam;
                            myCommand.Parameters["@date"] = ContractDateParam;
                            myCommand.Parameters["@pid"] = pipelineIDParam;
                            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
                    double progress = (double)i / range.Rows.Count * 100;
                    bgw.ReportProgress(Convert.ToInt32(progress));
                }

            }
        }
```

The i loop after it hits the limit(range.rows.count) gets reinitalised to 'startRow' and it happens only when I dont stop the debugger after processing one sheet and continue processing multiple sheets.

I am at my wits end tring to figure out what could cause this. Please help

**Update**

I forgot to add that this method is part of the Background Worker DoWork() method. When I try to execute it without using background worker I have no issues. I am forced to think the DoWork () method does not end and keeps calling the method causing the reinitialization. How can I let the DoWork method know that the work is over.

Comment: How are you assigning `range` ? There's nothing obvious in there which point to your loop restarting, but it might help to cut out the any irrelevant DB-related code.

Comment: `Excel.Range range = excel.Selection as Excel.Range;` and I pass this range to the method above.